# X509Certificate IssuedTo / IssuedBy for user display from X509Store

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I need to show a user the list of Certificates from the X509Store and want to display the same information as per the MMC 'Certificate' snap in. Specifically looking to retrieve the "Issued To" and "Issued By" values.

The 'Friendly name' is simple (string property of X509Certificate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Issuer` Property to get the Issuer and the `Subject` for Issued By.

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.aspx).

Comment: I'm still not able to see the "IssuedTo" field. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I do to iterate a store and get the IssuedTo and IssuedBy values.  You only need the middle bit, but this is a better working example snippet.

```
// Iterate localmachine personal store

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

foreach (var cert in store.Certificates)
{
    string s = String.Format("{0} ({1})", 
      cert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false), 
      cert.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, true)); 

    System.Console.WriteLine(s);
}

store.close();
```